# Code not giving a response (Quaternary Search Algorithm)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm new to coding, and im trying as a first project to create a quaternary search algorithm, I have tried doing it in a recursive matter but it gave me a "maximum recursion" error, so I tried doing it in an iterative manner, but this time It doesn't even give me a response and I don't know why, this is the code:

````
def quaternary_search(y,x):
    low = 0
    high = len(y) -1
    mid1 = 0
    mid2 = 0
    mid3 = 0
    while high>=low:
        mid1 = int(round(high/4))
        mid2 = int(round(high/2))
        mid3 = int(round(3*high/4))

        if y[mid1] == x:
            return mid1
        
        elif y[mid2] == x:
            return mid2

        elif y[mid3] == x:
            return mid3

        elif y[mid1] > x and y[mid2] > x and y[mid3] > x:
            high = mid1 - 1

        elif y[mid1] < x and y[mid2] > x and y[mid3] > x:
            low = mid1 + 1
            high = mid2 - 1

        elif y[mid1] < x and y[mid2] < x and y[mid3] > x:
            low = mid2 + 1
            high = mid3 - 1

        elif y[mid1] < x and y[mid2] < x and y[mid3] < x:
            low = mid3 + 1

    return -1

y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
x = int(input("What are you searching?"))

result = quaternary_search(y,x)

if result != -1:
    print("Element is at index",str(result))

else:
    print("Element is not found")

    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

just simply add `+1` to the x variable when passing it into the function. list indexes start at 0, so you need to add 1.

```
result = quaternary_search(y,x+1)
```

seems to work with that small change, here when I enter 8 it says it's at the 8th index.

```
What are you searching?8
Element is at index 8
```

Comment: try input `6` with your code, you will get a infinite loop